# $.ajax done function nor firing

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

I have the following code,

```
$(".delete.red").live("click", function () {
    var self = $(this);
    var loadUrl = $(this).attr('href');
    alert("clicked");
    //var interestParents = self.parents('div:eq(4)').attr("id");
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: loadUrl,
        dataType: "json"
    }).success(function (msg) {
        alert(msg);
        self.parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().remove();
        $(".selected strong").text(msg.icount)

    });
    return false;
});
```

What this code does it on click of a link it sends a request off to the clicked links href, it should then find the outermost parent of that link and remove itself from the markup.

Howevever the request is not getting to the `done()` function I am getting now feedback it is almost as if it is not being called, which seems strange as when I look at the network tab, I can see the links href has been access, and I can see `200 OK` response.

Waht is going on?

Comment: add a .error and check what error occurs. Is your response from the server valid json ?

Comment: Consider using `self.grandpa()`.

Comment: the json works fine in everyother request on the site.

Comment: My guess is that return false; is *potentially* the problem, pass e to the function() and do e.preventDefault instead and try it again.

Comment: e.preventDefault does not work in ie7 it breaks the scripts.

Comment: `self.parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().remove()` - are you kidding? use `closest`.

Comment: self.closest('li').remove(); would that do the same?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Make success part of the options object passed as an argument

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: loadUrl,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (msg) {
            alert(msg);
            self.parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().remove();
            $(".selected strong").text(msg.icount);
        }
});
```

The success callback has been deprecated in jQuery 1.8 according to the website

> **Deprecation Notice:** The jqXHR.success(), jqXHR.error(), and
>   jqXHR.complete() callbacks will be deprecated in jQuery 1.8. To
>   prepare your code for their eventual removal, use jqXHR.done(),
>   jqXHR.fail(), and jqXHR.always() instead.

According to the site, the **live** method has also been deprecated

> As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated. 
>   Use .on() to attach event handlers.

Comment: Was going to post basically the same.